# form_with problem with composite primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a scaffold with a composite primary key for the model:

```
> bin/rails generate scaffold WineItem wine:references vintage:string

class CreateWineItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table(:wine_items, primary_key: [:wine_id, :vintage]) do |t|
      t.references :wine, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.string :vintage

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I have been dealing with the issues related to that Rails `Active Record does not support composite primary key.`

**For example**:

For the `show` workaround:

route:

```
get '/wine_items/:wine_id/vintage/:vintage', to: 'wine_items#show', as: 'wine_item'
```

```
http://localhost:3000/wine_items/3/vintage/2019
```

in controller:

```
  def show
    @wine_item = WineItem.where({ wine_id: params[:wine_id], vintage: params[:vintage]})
  end
```

and in the view:

```
<p>
  <strong>Wine:</strong>
  <%= @wine_item.first.wine_id %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Vintage:</strong>
  <%= @wine_item.first.vintage %>
</p>
```

Everything ok, but for the `edit`:

route:

```
get '/wine_items/:wine_id/vintage/:vintage/edit', to: 'wine_items#edit', as: 'edit_wine_item'
```

```
http://localhost:3000/wine_items/3/vintage/2019/edit
```

In controller:

```
  def edit
    @wine_item = WineItem.where({ wine_id: params[:wine_id], vintage: params[:vintage]})
  end
```

In the `edit.html.erb`:

```
<%= render 'form', wine_item: @wine_item.first %>
```

but an error in the `_form.html.erb` in the `form_with` helper:

```
<%= form_with(model: wine_item, local: true) do |form| %>
```

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"wine_items", :format=>nil, :vintage=>"2019", :wine_id=>#<WineItem wine_id: 3, vintage: "2019", created_at: "2021-07-07 10:09:07", updated_at: "2021-07-07 10:09:07">}, possible unmatched constraints: [:wine_id]
```

I checked the routes:

```
        Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                          Controller#Action
    wine_items GET    /wine_items(.:format)                                wine_items#index
               POST   /wine_items(.:format)                                wine_items#create
 new_wine_item GET    /wine_items/new(.:format)                            wine_items#new
edit_wine_item GET    /wine_items/:wine_id/vintage/:vintage/edit(.:format) wine_items#edit
     wine_item GET    /wine_items/:wine_id/vintage/:vintage(.:format)      wine_items#show
               PATCH  /wine_items/:wine_id/vintage/:vintage(.:format)      wine_items#update
               PUT    /wine_items/:wine_id/vintage/:vintage(.:format)      wine_items#update
               DELETE /wine_items/:wine_id/vintage/:vintage(.:format)      wine_items#destroy
```

Thanks in advace

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you missed update(put/patch) route definition for it and also keep in mind that you have ability to define custom `url` and `method` for the form via helper options, [look it here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with) (form_with options section)